# Mean of a random variable

Tags: statistics

Two tire-quality experts examine stacks of tires
and assign a quality rating to each tire on a 3-point
scale. Let X denote the rating given by expert A and
Y denote the rating given by B. The following table
gives the joint distribution for X and Y .[image]

Can someone help us understand this chart...

Comment: How to use the chart? To find $f(2,3)$, the probability that expert A rates it 2 and expert B rates it 3, look at where row 2 intersects column 3. So $f(2,3)=0.05$ from the chart.

Comment: how would we calculate the mean for x and y?

Comment: For $x$, add up 1 times the percentage of all the values  that have $x=1$ plus 2 times ...  Same for $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the joint density.  To find $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$, you need the marginal densities.  That is, you need the density of just $X$ and the density of just $Y$, each of them by themselves.  We can get this quickly from the table by adding up each row and column.

For example, the probability that $X = 1$ and $Y = 1$ is $0.10$.  The probability of $X = 1$ and $Y = 2$ is $0.05$.  The probability of $X = 1$ and $Y = 3$ is $0.02$.  These are the only ways that $X$ can be $1$.  So, the probability that $X = 1$ is the sum, $0.1 + 0.05 + 0.02 = 0.17$.  Adding up the second row gives the probability that $X = 2$ and the third row the probability that $X = 3$.  Then, you have the density of $X$ and you find the expected value just as you would if $Y$ were never in the problem.  Similarly, add up the columns to get the marginal density of $Y$ and then calculate $\mu_Y$ from that.